# Ajax Security: JSON with an Object on the outside

Tags: php, json, ajax, security

As mentioned in [Owasp CheatSheet Series](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/AJAX_Security_Cheat_Sheet.html), in the section 'Protect against JSON Hijacking for Older Browsers', one should always return JSON with an object on the outside. As a result, the same reference asserts that a JSON like the following is exploitable:

```
[{"object": "inside an array"}]
```

It also states that the following JSON format is not exploitable:

```
 {"object": "not inside an array"}
```

However, when I run a query to the database, and use fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC), it brings the array exactly in the first exploitable JSON format. How can I make JSON from the fetchAll in the second non-exploitable format?

**EDITED**

The following is my php fetchAll() script:

```js
    public function retrieveData() {
        $conn = parent::connected();
        $inactive = '0';
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `category` WHERE term_status != :status";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam("status", $inactive, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
```

Appreciations.

Comment: `fetchAll()` is designed to return an array of rows, so this will always be a `[..]` type json string.  If you just have one row, just fetch one row or use `fetchAll()[0]`

Comment: It is not just one row. So, how can we bypass the security vulnerability as mentioned in the Owasp Cheat Sheet? Thanks dear @Nigel Ren

Comment: As the third example from the page you linked says, you can make your response object to look like `{result:[{"object": "inside an array"}]}`. Basically, always return a single object, with a property that holds your result array. If you show the code that runs `fetchAll` and the response method, I can give a more concise example.

Comment: I added that to the question itself, dear @SpeedOfRound

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, always return a single object, with a property that holds your result array.
For you it would look like this.

```
return [ 'result' => $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ];
```

Which will return something like:

```
{ 'result': [ ...rows ] }
```

Comment: Dear @SpeedOfRound, may you please add some more detail to your answer. How can I use the data in this JSON format in Ajax success function. This format was not accepted by datatables plugin as well. Can you please explain a little bit. Much Appreciated.

Comment: Its hard to say without knowing how your using it. If your feeding the ajax response into datatables, where you would previously pass it an `ajaxresponse`, now you would pass it `ajaxresponse.result`. This is going outside the scope of the original question though.

Comment: Suppose the result is {"result":[{"id":"1","term":"1"}]}, then how can I use the value of id, and term in ajax response. Previously, I used result.id and it returned the value properly. Now what I should do? The answer is much appreciated. @SpeedOfRound

Comment: You could not have done that if your database was returning more than one row, you need some way to either iterate through the response array, or to search the array for the needed object by id with [.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: I really appreciate it. All the best.